# Update records in SQL by looking up in different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

I am copying data from few tables in SQL server A to B. I have a set of staging tables in B and need to update some of those staging tables based on updated values in final target table in B.

Example:

Server B:

StagingTable1:

```
ID | NAME | CITY
1    ABC    XYZ
2    BCD    XXX
```

StagingTable2:

```
ID | AGE | Table1ID(FK)
10    15    1
20    16    2
```

After Copying StagingTable1 to TargetTable1 (ID's get auto polulated and I get new ID's, now ID 1 becomes 2 and ID 2 becomes 3)

TargetTable1:

```
ID  | NAME | CITY
1     PQR    YYY  (pre-existing record)
2     ABC    XYZ
3     BCD    XXX
```

So now before I can copy the StagingTable2 I need to update the Table1ID column in it by correct values from TargetTable1.

StagingTable2 should become:

```
ID | AGE | Table1ID(FK)
10    15    2
20    16    3
```

I am writing a stored procedure for this and not sure how do I lookup and update the records in staging tables?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `(name, city)` tuples are unique in `StagingTable1` and `TargetTable1`, you can use an updatable common table expression to generate the new mapping and assign the corresponding values:

```
with cte as (
    select st2.Table1ID, tt1.id
    from StagingTable2 st2
    inner join StagingTable1 st1 on st1.ID = st2.Table1ID
    inner join TargetTable1 tt1 on tt1.name = st1.name and tt1.city = st1.city
)
update cte set Table1ID = id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3cbe2538ffeacd0e80772150db0c3b59)** - content of `StagingTable2` after the `update`:

```
id | age | Table1ID
-: | --: | -------:
10 |  15 |        2
20 |  16 |        3
```